# How can I access other javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an app and different javascript files.

From HTML I want to be able to access var from those different javascript files.

How should I do that??

**EXAMPLE JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var one = {
  att1: 'myString1',
  att2: 'myString2'
  ...
};

var two = {
  att1: 'myString3',
  att2: 'myString4',
  ...
};
```

**EXAMPLE HTML:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/idiomas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryMobile/jquery-1.11.0.js"/></script>
......
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, missed one part. This is where I try to access the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var atrib1 = document.getElementById("idAtr1");
  var atrib4 = document.getElementById("idAtr4");
  .....
  atrib1.innerHTML = one.att1;
  atrib4.innerHTML = two.att2;
  ....
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code where you are trying to access the variables? What have you tried?

Comment: Simply refer the js files in your html and you should be able to acces them

Comment: First of all change the sequence of your javascript libraries, jQuery should be first to be loaded

Comment: You mean you want to access them with jQuery? like so: two.att1

Comment: Yeah, and if you need same variables in few files, consider building one file... Maybe the objects are collided, and one file should be used...

Comment: Just eddited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to maintain hierarchy. For example.

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>  
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

then you can able to access **file1.js** variables on **file2.js** but can't access **file2.js** on file1.js. Rules is javascript read files sequentially. So, if you try to access function/variables/object before they are available will get error.

Otherwise, If you want to access both files variable, you may try followings:

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>  
<script src="file2.js"></script>
<!-- import your js files that contain those variable -->
<script>
  var atrib1 = document.getElementById("idAtr1");
  var atrib4 = document.getElementById("idAtr4");
  //import your js files above and then call it.
  atrib1.innerHTML = one.att1;
  atrib4.innerHTML = two.att2;

</script>
```

If you have still doubt. Mention that on comment. We'll try to help :)

Comment: Just eddited question. I'm trying your solution

Comment: @Sascuash check edited answer. If you still doubt. I'm unable to understand your problem at this stage, better you put your full code example, so anyone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add those js files in your HTML, and access those variables normally.

```
<!-- Your script containing the variables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/idiomas.js"></script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(one);  // Access the variable normally
</script>
```